# Using JavaScript function as a startpoint for webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JavaScript-button that makes page autofocus on a certain object. Can I make this the starting point of my webpage?

I tried a "winWidth, winHeight / 2" code to try make the page start off in the middle (this would be satisfactory on PC, not sure about mobile), but the code didn't work regardless so I'm back to square one.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("zoom");
    elmnt.scrollIntoView();
    }
</script>
```

That's the JavaScript, a simple zoom function so when button is pressed it zooms into a ghost horizontal rule and gives viewer ideal eyefocus for what I want them to see.

Here's the code of the button and the HR:

```
<div class="Concept_Button">
        <a onclick="myFunction()">Konsept</a>
</div>
```

```
<div class="zoomPoint" id="zoom">
        <hr style="color:blue;background- 
        color:blue;opacity:0.00;border:none;height:1px;">
</div>
```

It starts naturally at the top of the page where you get forwarded if you press the "Order" button I have on the header at the top of the page.

Therefore, I want the viewer to start further down the page as the start point when you first load the page, and then only go upwards if you press the "Order" button, leading to a "Order form" to fill out.

Thanks in advance and I will hope to answer all questions or if I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: There are several ways to fire a JavaScript function after the page has loaded, search for how to do this.

Comment: @seano666 I really did try searching my way through this but it wasn't until I added keyword "on page load" that I really found a viable code. Thanks for your input regardless, I got it to work instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to add an `onload` attribute to the body tag.

```
<body onload="scroll()">
   ...
   <div id="example"></div>
   ...
</body>
```

```
function scroll(){
   document.getElementById("example").scrollIntoView();
}
```